# Scheduling tool with callbacks

Tags: asynchronous, scheduling

I try to develop amateur web games (just for fun) and I'm looking for a tool that allows me to (with a use case) :

- Enqueue items in a system, with a finish_at property. *Typically, it would be used for the units production queue* ;
- Be able to alter the finish_at property of an item. *Eh, if the frostwyrm attacks the barrack, its production is temporarily stopped* ;
- Be able to setup callback on the progression (at given percentages). *When a player builds a Wonder, I want to notify his ennemies about the progress* ;

Do you know such a tool ? If you don't, what technologies can you recommend to me in order to built that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a doubly linked list, where each node can be a member of multiple different lists at the same time:

```
struct node
{
    struct node *factory_prev;
    struct node *factory_next;
    struct node *finish_prev;
    struct node *finish_next;
    struct node *progress_prev;
    struct node *progress_next;
};
```

The first list links all the items produced by this factory; the list base is with the factory object. When the factory is attacked, you can walk this list to find all items that are now delayed, so you can take them out of the other lists.

The second list links all items being produced, ordered by the time they are finished. Looking at the first element can tell you in O(1) whether an item is finished.

The third list links all items that broadcast progress events, again sorted by when the next such event occurs. This mechanism is very similar to the "finish" list and could theoretically be merged, however having a separate, shorter list allows you to find the items that need progress broadcasts faster.

As these are doubly linked lists, as soon as you have a pointer to a node you know how to unlink it from all other lists as well. Be aware that in a multithreaded program you might need some form of locking still.

The alternative would be to reschedule items that have been delayed at the time when they would ordinarily have been produced; this is however pretty difficult to get right for items that also have progress reports.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Anyway, I don't think i am able to write such a daemon (i'm not a C guru ^^, and what i can't wrote probably never scale well). I believed there are tools for this kind of needs (or approaching ones). Maybe i should base my work on tools like the command "at", i don't know…